# Why was my answer deleted when there are other similar answers?

Tags: discussion

I need to know why my answer was deleted despite there are similar answers like mine.

Here the link for the question:

[Displaying a GIF in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457959/displaying-a-gif-in-silverlight)

Comment: The first answer? or the second answer? I think you know why the second one was deleted...

Comment: @MarcGravell - the second was self deleted.

Answer (score 4):

A comment was left at the time, explaining why answers that are *essentially* just a link are not seen favorably. I have now converted the answer to a comment instead of an answer.

Normally, if a moderator adds a commend and deletes a post, the poster can continue to see the comment in their inbox. In this case, however, the person who added the comment was **not** a moderator, so it didn't get preserved. The moderator probably saw the comment and thought "that explains it fine", and deleted without adding a comment. Which means you might not have seen it. However, the comment that was added was:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Now, you might reasonable say:

> but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462291/23354) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457972/23354) are also not much more than a link!

Yes. They were also added in 2009, and can only sensibly be judged by the guidelines / practices of that time.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will be very careful

Comment: Perhaps some of those other answers should be squelched now too.

Answer (score 2):

From Stack Overflow: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed".

Includes:

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

Comment: my answer doesn't contain any of the above reasons, thanks anyway

Comment: @user3746785 "barely more than a link to an external site"

Comment: Please, please do not use code formatting for things that are not code.